# A trigonometric equation with a parameter

Tags: trigonometry

For which the value of $p$ equation

$$\cos^3 x + p \cos x + p + 1 = 0$$

It has exactly 3 solution in the range of $[0;2\pi]$?

I don't have a idea :(

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$\cos^3 x + p \cos x + p + 1 = (\cos x + 1)(\cos^2 x - \cos x + 1) + p(\cos x + 1)$

So $\cos x = -1$ or $\cos^2 x - \cos x + p + 1 = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Assume $$\cos x = α $$

Then:

$$ α^3+pα+p+1 = 0$$

Because it's a polynomial of degree 3 it has 3 roots. By inspection, the first root is -1.

*...But my domain doesn't include -1!*

Yes, but trigonometric functions are circular, which means any valid solution *s* generates an infinity of valid solutions for $$s+k2\pi$$ for k being an integer.

Anyway, you know how to find the first solution. Now I suggest you have a read [at this](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/synthdiv.htm) which will show you have to obtain a second order polynomial equation, [which will yield the remaining two roots](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/quadform.htm).